# What is "starting" static distribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I'm not sure if I call everything correctly in English in here, but i have a problem with stochastic processes - Markov chains to be more specific.

I'm calculating the "starting" stationary distribution, which in my case equals $PI = [2/7  ,5/7]$. Fine. But how can I interpret this values?

Comment: With probabiltiy $\frac{2}{7}$ the markov chain starts at "State A" and with probability $\frac{5}{7}$ it starts at "State B".